# Get fasta source file from blast database name

Tags: bioinformatics, blast

I am currently writing a library that uses the `-outfmt 10` option of Blast, which give you a CSV instead of the pretty human readable format.

Like

```
tblastn -db dmel_a -query somequery.faa -outfmt 10
```

The problem is, I want to access the db source file so I can extract some sequences after processing. The only way I know how to do this, is to use the remove `-outfmt 10` and run the blast twice. Then I parse the human readable output for the line that says:

```
Database: Source.fas
```

But, that only works if `title` is not specified when creating the database in `makeblastdb`. The `stitle` of `outfmt 10` seems to be the fasta header line anyway. I cannot just look for the database name and then a `.fna, .fas, .faa` because you can name the database differently than the source file.

Is there another way to extract the fasta source file from the blast database name? I do not see one in the list of `outfmt` options. Or am I blind today?

Comment: This question might be better asked here:  http://www.biostars.org/ - where it is more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that worked based on a Biostar question, and a [blasted bioinformatics](http://blastedbio.blogspot.com/2012/10/my-ids-not-good-enough-for-ncbi-blast.html) blog post. Requires Blast+ 2.2.28 if your fasta doesnt follow NCBI naming exactly.

When you create the blast database, use the `-parse_seqids` flag. Then with blastdbcmd, you can extract a range of the sequence

```
blastdbcmd -db t/blastTest/dmel -range 1-10 -entry some_seq_id
```